# In Django, how to display time which updates every minute?

Tags: javascript, django

Using tag `{% now %}`, I can display the time, but the time is static and doesn't update every minute.
Is there anyway to update this time?

Is it possible to do this with javascript's `setInterval` and django's `{% now %}`?

Tried this:

```
<script>
setInterval(function () {
    $("#current_time").text("{% now "jS F Y H: i " %}");
}, 60 * 1000); // 60 * 1000 milsec
</script>
```

But this doesnt work as django renders now value only once(when page loads) and it remains same all time

Comment: Why don't you simply render the time using only JavaScript?

Comment: "Is it possible to do this with javascript's setInterval and django's {% now %}" It's not. You can start with `{% now %}` in a js variable and then continue with that in js

Comment: yes, I was wondering if it would be possible involving Django's now template tag. If its not possible, ill do using js. Thanks

Comment: Even if Django updates the value in the background you have to actually refresh the page to see what has changed. Since you haven't used AJAX request the page is not reloaded automatically. That is the reason Django doesn't update time after every minute onto your DOM.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function startTime()
{
    var today=new Date();
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();

    m=checkTime(m);
    s=checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
    t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
}
    function checkTime(i)
{
    if (i<10)
{
    i="0" + i;
}
    return i;
}
</script>

<body onload="startTime()">

<div class="tile-content" id="txt">
```

if you don't want seconds delete s var

check if usefull